# how do I 'hard refresh' a shared directory?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player

VMWare player 4.0.1 build-528992

I added a file to a shared directory in Windows 7. When I `ls -l` that directory in Ubuntu 11 it looks like: (2nd line)

```
ls: cannot access  item_spec.rb: No such file or directory

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 300 2012-01-11 12:05 user_spec.rb
-????????? ? ?    ?        ?          ?     item_spec.rb
```

How can I get the folder to "refresh"? I need to use this file in Ubuntu. I think it will be present if I restart the VM, but that seems excessive. This looks like a bug. I asked this question on the VMWare forums and haven't gotten a response.

Output of `ls -l` for parent:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8192 2012-01-13 13:26 the_project
```

Comment: What are the permissions for the shared directory? Post the output of `ls -l parent_of_shared_dir`.This can be caused by not having exectute (`x`) permissions on the shared directory, so you are prevented to display information about the file with `ls`.

Comment: @hesse thanks for the suggestion. Looks like all the permissions are there. Updated OP.

Comment: Why the downvote? WTF.

Comment: How did you create the file? What are the permissions of the parent directory and its files in Windows?

Comment: @hesse I'm having trouble recreating the issue. I saw it twice the other day, but I can't create a file today and get it to happen. Tried creating via Windows Explorer and via RubyMine. Both files were immediately available in Ubuntu. I'll leave the question up, maybe someone will see what's going on.

Comment: @hesse OK it happened again. I created the file in RubyMine. Ugh, if I tell RubyMine about this issue they'll say "Oh that's VMWare's fault" and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reasonable solution to this, but not a real answer.

`touch file_to_create.rb`

Create the file in Ubuntu, then add it to source or edit it or what-not in Windows. Never ever create the file in Windows, VMWare doesn't seem to be able to deal with it.

If you rename a file in Windows and it comes up `????` in Ubuntu, then `touch` the new file name in Ubuntu and it'll come back, with the correct contents.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue is the same as when using a media player, SMB2 stops the refresh in windows 7

[this link might help with a tool to do it.](http://forums.seagate.com/t5/FreeAgent-Theater-and-GoFlexTV/Tool-that-Addresses-issues-with-Windows-7-Sharing-and-SMB2/td-p/179148)

Comment: It would be more helpful if you did not just link to another site, but actually post the useful information.